# pre_get_posts having no effect on my category archive

Tags: pre-get-posts

By default, site is set to show 4 posts per page, but on a particular category (id 76) archive I want it to show 12. I've included this code in functions.php but it's not working. What am I missing here:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','filter_archive');
function filter_archive( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin && is_category('76') && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', '12');    
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a typo there, should be: **is_admin()**. You should enable debugging by setting **define('WP_DEBUG', true);** in wp-config.php to see such errors.
Also there's no need of returning anything in action hook.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts','filter_archive', 1 );
function filter_archive( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_category('76') && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set('posts_per_page', '12');
}
```

***Sidenote***: personally I prefer to rely on slugs than on IDs in such cases. If the website needs to be set up from scratch on new database, I have more flexibility. I also avoid inconsitencies between development instance and production instance which have (and should have) different databases.

Comment: Thanks, of course! I figured there had to be something simple I was overlooking.